# Current Mirror - Find Acceptable Range of Vb

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I'm stuck on part A - in particular finding Vb range

Here's what I have so far

[image]

Now, here's where I get lost
[image]

I have no idea if my method is correct. I'm confident about my value for Vx but no clue about Vb.

Comment: What happens if Vb is ZERO? what goes wrong? anything? What if Vb is VDD? what goes wrong? anything? View the two upper FETS M0 and M3 as "shields"; in what region  of FET operation must the work? cutoff? nope.Triode? sat? or in some boundary region? You might draw out the drain-characteristics, and then think. Or use more analysis.

Comment: All MOSFETs need to work in saturation for a cascode current mirror at least. If Vb is zero, Vgs0 will be negative probably and so M0 will be in cut-off and so will M3.

Comment: *All MOSFETs need to work in saturation for a cascode current mirror at least.* Not true! Only the mirror NMOS: M1 and M2 need to operate in saturation mode. M0 and M3 will only operate in saturation mode if Vb is high enough and the voltage at the drain of M3 is high enough. M0 and M3 can also operate in triode mode and the circuit will still work.